# Kerberos authentication in windows service

Tags: c#, kerberos

I am new on kerberos authentication and don't know anything about it. I have the server name, username and password ready for it.

I need to authenticate users from stand alone windows application. Can somebody please help?

I did not find much help on googling.

Appreciate any thought.

Comment: Don't use Kerberos Authentication, use Ntlm instead.

Comment: @Aron: Sometimes there is no choice. The server won't change just for my client program.

Comment: If you don't know anything about Windows with/Kerberos/NTLM then you wouldn't know what is possible. Generally windows authentication is actually SPEGNO negotiate which then either uses Kerberos or NTLM for the actually authentication. Use NTLM.

Comment: Still the majority of the pain comes from setting up the Kerberos server along with the SPN. I have lost a literal man month to that particular gem. @NicolasRaoul

Comment: If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 7):

In Kerberos you authenticate not with pair username/password, but by attaching Kerberos token, which you can grab from CredentialsCache.

```
WebRequest WReq = WebRequest.Create (MyURI);
WReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk7437c8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The second line will give you NTLM or Kerberos credentials. You'll get Kerberos credentials when:

- your application is started by a domain user account
- SPN or UPN for the server in present in Kerberos KeyDistributionCentre
- Server is configured to receive Kerberos tokens, at least: you must provide it a password.

When you execute 'CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials', your application uses underlying mechanisms to generate SPNEGO token for you. Inside it, will be Keberos or NTLM ticket. Here's how it works:

- description of environment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480562.aspx
- what goes on a client computer (SSPI implementation is used to generate tickets) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480609.aspx

Comment: thanks greenmaker. I actually needed to grab the token and was looking for C# example of it. I cannot have any dependency on the IIS BTW. Can you please link me to an example, I was not able to find one on google. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk7437c8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Your app must be running on a domain user account, because only then CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials will return Kerberos credentials.