# Authenticate the identity of the local Windows domain

Tags: windows, security, authentication, active-directory

We have an application to which I want to add a feature that grants additional access to domain admins of our corporate domain. The application runs outside of our domain as well. Obviously, I can query what domain the machine is joined to, and if it matches our corporate domain, enable the feature, but I'm concerned that a hypothetical "advanced" hacker might create their own domain at home with exactly the same name. How can I verify the identity of the domain, so that I can enable the feature only for our actual corporate domain, not just any domain whose name matches?

Comment: `I can query what domain the machine is joined to, and if it matches our corporate domain, enable the feature, but I'm concerned that a hypothetical "advanced" hacker might create their own domain at home with exactly the same name.` - To resolve this, you'd need a connection from the Internet system having that application to your AD Server, to verify the system's authenticity!

Comment: Assuming I have such a connection, how do I verify the authenticity?

Comment: I hope [this question on "Kerberos Authentication in Windows Service"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781360/kerberos-authentication-in-windows-service) answers your query!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that it does. See, the problem is, I can get a local cached token, and I can talk to the domain the machine is on and ask it if the token is valid, and I can check that the domain the machine is on has the right name, but isn't all of that defeated if an attacker simply sets up his own domain with the same name and signs into it? The app will see a token and the token will validate and the domain will have the right name, but won't actually be the _same_ domain, and that's what I want to validate.

Comment: I think you're just confused because of the same DNS name! Please be aware that every AD domain has a unique GUID, and the possibility of it being exactly same and used anywhere else is almost impossible! And, also the SID and the related authentication wouldn't be same just because of the same domain name. You may further like to check this link: https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/feature/SIDs-versus-GUIDs.

Comment: Is it impossible to deliberately create a domain with a particular GUID, then?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct! You can't intentionally achieve a particular GUID.

Comment: Technically anything is possible, but from what you're telling me, it would take a bad actor of incredible sophistication to make that change, then? Like, they'd have to access the hard disk offline and have a tool that grokked the proprietary storage Active Directory uses for its object database in order to overwrite the domain's ObjectGuid. Speculating, if it's not compressed or encrypted, it might be doable without knowing the format with a find/replace of the GUID's bytes. But, it's definitely not something a casual attacker would be able to do. Does that sound like a fair assessment?

Comment: *... the proprietary storage Active Directory uses for its object database in order to overwrite the domain's ObjectGuid...* -> the object GUID can never be overwritten technically. Aside that, the trust of the system with AD server and the internal password being used can't satisfy the second AD domain with same name too. This is the food for thought for you! You probably seem to be thinking too much about raw manipulation of AD database, that too of all secret hidden fields, which is not possible in this scenario.